# Jquery dropdown change event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

how can I write a code to use jquery dropdown change event?in the below code I have created a drop down using  . now I want to further trigger an event in which it dynamically chooses the options given by the user. for example in my code i have created a drop down in which user chooses the amount of iron ore.if he chooses 1000kg the further process like amount of slag in kg is automatically fetched by the event.the user need not to choose the amount of slag. it must be fetched dynamically when the user clicks on the drop down button of amount of iron ore.the code is below...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>BLAST FURNACE</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
    .spad{
        padding: 80px;
    }
    #my_image{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    .cont{
        width: 700px;
        height: 700px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<label for="IRON ORE-SELECT">Choose Iron Ore (in kg):</label>
<select name="IRON ORE" id="IRON-ORE-SELECT">
    <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
    <option value="1000">1000</option>
    <option value="1500">1500</option>
    <option value="1800">1800</option>
    <option value="2000">2000</option>
    <option value="2500">2500</option>
    <option value="3000">3000</option>
    <option value="3500">3500</option>
    <option value="4000">4000</option>
    <option value="4500">4000</option>
    <option value="5000">5000</option>
</select>

<h1>BLAST FURNACE SIMULATION</h1>
<p>BLAST FURNACE SIMULATION PROCESS.</p>
<!-- <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
    <span class="spanloader">

</span>
</canvas> -->
<!-- <button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date()">
CLICK HERE TO  CHARGE IRON ORE FLUX INTO BLAST FURNACE.</button> -->
<!-- <input type="button" id="btnnext" value="CLICK HERE TO  CHARGE IRON ORE FLUX INTO BLAST FURNACE" /> -->
<!-- <script>
var img=document.createElement("img");
img.src
</script> -->


<!-- 
<p id="demo"></p> -->
<div class="cont">
    <div class="row spad">
        <img id="my_image" src="#"  class="img-fluid"/>
    </div>
    <span class="spanloader">
        <span>set Loading Image Image</span>
    </span>
</div>    




<!-- <input type="button" id="btnnext" value="CLICK HERE TO  CHARGE IRON ORE FLUX INTO BLAST FURNACE" /> -->
<input type="button" id="btn01" value="CLICK HERE TO SHOW EMPTY BLAST FURNACE " />
<input type="button" id="btn02" value="CLICK HERE TO CHARGE IRON ORE FLUX INTO BLAST FURNACE" />
<input type="button" id="btn03" value="CLICK HERE TO SHOW BLAST FURNACE" />
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#btn01').click(function () {       
        $("#my_image").attr("src", "empty.png");
    });
    $('#btn02').click(function () {       
        $("#my_image").attr("src","Sequence01_1.gif");
    });
    $('#btn03').click(function () {       
        $("#my_image").attr("src", "BLASTFURNACE.png");
    });

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#IRON-ORE-SELECT').on("keyup input", function () {       
    //do something
});
```

or

```
$('#IRON-ORE-SELECT').change(function () {       
    //do something
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just a suggestion: A small comment on your code pieces would help understanding the solution you provide.

Comment: @juagicre You can find an explanation on the jquery change event here https://api.jquery.com/change/